# NP completeness of classes of spanning trees

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, np

I am teaching a complexity course, and I want to give some examples of similar looking problems such that one is in P, and the other is NP complete.

This made me think of the following problem: does a given graph contain a spanning tree with a given degree sequence? This is obviously easy for the sequence $n-1,1,...,1$ and hard for $2,...,2,1,1$.  Is there a general answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lemke has shown that it is NP-hard to decide whether a cubic graph on $n=2k$ vertices has a spanning tree in which $k+1$ vertices have degree $1$ and $k-1$ vertices have degree $3$.

> P. Lemke:
>   "The maximum-leaf spanning tree problem in cubic graphs is NP-complete."
>   IMA publication no. 428, University of Minnesota, Mineapolis, 1988.
>   https://www.ima.umn.edu/Maximum-Leaf-Spanning-Tree-Problem-Cubic-Graphs-NP-Complete

- Lemke's result implies the NP-completeness of deciding whether there exists a spanning tree without vertices of degree $2$.
- A slight modification of Lemke's reduction shows that the following problem is NP-complete for every fixed integer $p\ge4$: Decide whether there exists a spanning tree, in which every non-leaf vertex has degree at least $p$.
- The same modification shows that the following problem is NP-complete for every fixed integer $p\ge4$: Decide whether there exists a spanning tree, in which every vertex degree lies in $\{1,p\}$.